# Listbox with dictionary, selectedItem on initial page load

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a dictionary which takes a string and a double, and I'm trying to get a selected element of the dictionary to be automatically selected (and highlighted) when I open the page that contains the listbox.  I can get this working with a list of strings, but can't get it working with the dictionary.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="MyLbStyle"
           TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
        <Style.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"
                             Color="Yellow" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey }"
                             Color="Yellow" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}"
                             Color="Black" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey}"
                             Color="Black" />
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<DockPanel Height="Auto"
           Width="Auto">
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyDict, Mode=OneWay}"
             Style="{ StaticResource MyLbStyle}"
             DockPanel.Dock="Top"
             Height="130"
             SelectedValuePath="Key"
             SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedVal, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
             FontSize="18"
             Margin="0,0,0,20">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DockPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key, Mode=OneWay}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value, Mode=OneWay}" />
                </DockPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</DockPanel>
```

And the VM

```
public class NumericParameterPageViewModel : ActionSelectionPage
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, IMyInterface> _valStorage = new Dictionary<string, IMyInterface>();
    private IMyInterface _selectedParameter;

    public ListBoxPage()
    {
    }

    public IMyInterface MyItem
    {
        get { return _selectedParameter; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty( ref _selectedParameter, value );
        }
    }

    public string SelectedVal
    {
        get
        {
            return _x;
        }
        set
        {
            SetProperty( ref _x, value );
            MyItem = _valStorage[ _x ];
        }
    }

    private string _x;

    public Dictionary<string, double> MyDict { get; } = new Dictionary<string, double>();

    public override void OnNavigatedTo(
        NavigationContext navigationContext )
    {
        var p = navigationContext.Parameters[ "ParameterList" ] as IMyInterface[];
        foreach (var item in p)
        {
            MyDict.Add( item.ID.Name, item.CurrentValue );
            _valStorage.Add( item.ID.Name, item );
        }
        SelectedItem = navigationContext.Parameters["ParamterID"] as IMyInterface;
        SelectedVal = MyDict.First().Key;
        base.OnNavigatedTo( navigationContext );
    }
}
```

All interface names here are made up, if two are slightly different (binding wise) it's because I cocked up manually changing them for the example.

Although it actually contains much more, for now assume IMyInterface just contains a string name, and a double value.  (I apologize for the messy code / naming, still prototyping this)

Comment: Sorry, that was just me editing to remove random extra bits.  Both are called the same thing in actual code, I'll edit to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the `Style` (and not the `ItemContainerStyle`) property to a `ListBox` style:

```
<Style x:Key="MyLbStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"
                             Color="Yellow" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey }"
                             Color="Yellow" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}"
                             Color="Black" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey}"
                             Color="Black" />
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

---

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyDict, Mode=OneWay}"
                         Style="{StaticResource MyLbStyle}"
                         DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                         SelectedValuePath="Key"
                         SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedVal, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DockPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key, Mode=OneWay}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value, Mode=OneWay}" />
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Made the change, but the issue is still there.  Once an item is manually selected things highlight fine, it just seems to be the initial setting when you enter the page which it doesn't like.

Comment: Are the items turning yellow when you select them?

Comment: Yes, after selection they're highlighting fine.  It's just on page entry they aren't highlighting.

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of your issue then because I can't reproduce base on the (lack of) information you have provided: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Also make sure that you actually select an item in the dictionary. Try this: SelectedVal = p.First().Name;

Comment: Okay I've stripped back the entire page to the listbox only, and the viewmodel to do the same.  I've also tried setting the SelectedVal in my example to MyDict.First().Key;

Comment: Another odd thing I've just spotted while playing around.  

If I give up on the SelectedValue stuff, and set SelectedIndex="0" it still fails to highlight.  HOWEVER

If I an a Loaded event, and in that event set lb.SelectedIndex = 0; the item highlights correctly.  Wondering if it's doing something weird in the back end after loading the page.

Comment: I've eventually managed to resolve the problem.  I think it's because the dictionary isn't observable, and it's being added to the VM after construction via the NavigationContext (which would also explain why I had the issue and you couldn't reproduce you)

Removing the dictionary, and replacing it with an ObservableCollection of Tuples seems to have done the trick.

Comment: Along with setting the ListBox style?

Comment: Sorry, was still playing with the implementation, in the end had to create a class to hold the name and value so I could edit it as I went.  Observable collection did seem to be the reason why it wasn't working though as an observable collection of KVP and Tuple both worked, while the dict did not.  Had a few other issues, but those were minor things from changing from a dictionary.

Although the answer didn't fix the problem, talking to you helped me reach the solution.  Thanks for your time.